# cmake/ctest: is it possible to use the creation of build targets as tests?

Tags: c++, code-generation, cmake, ctest

I have a program which reads a description of a file format (ISO 10303-11 for the curious) and generates c++ from it. The generated code is compiled into a library, and the library is linked with various executables to read/write that file format.

I have CMake set up to build the generator program and generate libraries for whichever file formats are specified at configuration time.

Now, I want to add tests. These tests are identical to steps that are already done in the build process - must I redo these steps in a CTest script, or is there a way to tell ctest to build a target and capture any error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough version of ctest (most recent official release is 2.8.6) then you can use the NAME/COMMAND signature of add_test, in conjunction with the cmake --build command line option, to build specific targets in your build tree.

For example, the following should work, assuming a custom target (or library or executable target) named "tgt1":

```
add_test(NAME test.build.tgt1
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIRECTORY}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target tgt1 --config $<CONFIGURATION>
)
```

This works cross-platform with the same syntax everywhere. It even works with multi-configuration generators, like Visual Studio and Xcode.

Comment: Thank you for this, it makes cross-platform support much easier than whatever I would have concocted. I used it, along with set_target_properties and set_test_properties:  `set_target_properties( ${target} PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ON )` and `set_tests_properties( build_${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEPENDS generate_${SCHEMA_SHORT_NAME} LABELS schema_build )`, for example.   I've created a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/1304839) with working code for anyone else who needs to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saying `enable_testing()` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, then calling `add_test()` to make a test target?  I think you can do everything in one consolidated build script if you follow the CMake documentation.

Comment: Yes, I have used both of those. My problem is in figuring out how to get ctest to do a partial build and then run the tests.