# Build custom CMake target from CTest

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a custom target that runs a test when "built", which is provided to me by a custom function belonging to an external dependency (i.e., it is opaque to me and I have no control over its definition).

How do I invoke building this target as a CTest test case? Is this considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: `I have a custom target that runs a test when "built", which is provided to me by a custom function belonging to an external dependency` I do not understand. How does a target runs a custom function? `How do I invoke building this target as a CTest test case?` How do you invoke it in the command line? Do the same.

Comment: @KamilCuk The custom target runs a command (see `COMMAND` in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)). From the command line I would do `ninja <the_custom_target>` or `make <the_custom_target>`, but this is potentially build system dependent.

Comment: So, do you want a single *test* to behave like as building a specific CMake target? If yes, then have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760605/cmake-ctest-is-it-possible-to-use-the-creation-of-build-targets-as-tests) which seems about the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to configure a cmake project that adds a custom target, you're able to see the cmake sources where this is added. Otherwise those sources wouldn't be available. This would allow you to turn `add_custom_target` commands equivalent `add_test` commands.

If you're not supposed to look into the cmake logic providing the test cases there may be the option of defining a custom cmake function that can be called to extract the `COMMAND` arguments ect. for use with either `add_custom_target` or `add_test`, so if you're collaborating with the people creating the "test" logic, you may be able to rewrite their cmake logic.

---

If you have no other option though, you could still create a test that builds a specific target.

```
function(add_target_build_test TEST_NAME TARGET_NAME)

    get_property(IS_MULTI_CONFIG_GENERATOR GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
    set(CONFIG_PARAM)
    if(IS_MULTI_CONFIG_GENERATOR)
        set(CONFIG_PARAM --config $<CONFIG>)
    endif()

    add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME} COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CONFIG_PARAM} --target ${TARGET_NAME})
endfunction()

add_target_build_test(my_test extern_target)
```

I'd avoid doing this though, if possible.